# Passing a react-query trpc query as a hook parameter

Tags: typescript, react-query, trpc.io, t3

I'd like to make a generic hook that takes `useQuery` as a parameter and handles pagination.

That means my trpc query will always provide a `skip` and a `take` parameter. And it will always return a `count` in the response and an array of `items`.

```
function usePagination(query){
  const [skip, take] = useSomethingThatManagesThis();

  const response = query.useQuery({
    skip,
    take,
  });
  
  return useMemo(() => ({
    items: response.data?.items,
    count: response.data?.count
  }), [response]);
}

function MyComponent() {
  const paginated = usePagination(api.user.list);
  
  const firstUserEmail = paginated.items?.[0].email;
}
```

It works in vanilla javascript, but I'm struggling to type it correctly.

I tried to naively reuse trpc client types, but I'm not able to distinguish request type (take, query) and response type (items).

```
import {
  AnyProcedure,
  AnyQueryProcedure,
  inferProcedureOutput,
} from "@trpc/server";

interface BaseInput {
  skip: number;
  take: number;
}

type UseDatatableArgs<TData extends AnyQueryProcedure> = {
  query?: {
    useQuery: (input: BaseInput) => ProcedureUseQuery<
      { count: number } & AnyProcedure,
      string
    > & {
      data: {
        count: number;
        items: inferProcedureOutput<TData>;
      };
    };
  };
};

function usePagination<TData extends AnyQueryProcedure>(query){
  const [skip, take] = useSomethingThatManagesThis();

  const response = query.useQuery({
    skip,
    take,
  });
  
  return useMemo(() => ({
    items: response.data?.items,
    count: response.data?.count
  }), [response]);
}
```

But I'm having no items typing in the response

```
function MyComponent() {
  const paginated = usePagination(api.user.list);
  
  const firstUserEmail = paginated.items?.[0].email; // paginated.items is any
}
```

I'm currently having a workaround by using types inferring utilities provided by TRPC, but I'd love to deduct that from the query

```
export type RouterOutputs = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>;

function MyComponent() {
  const paginated = usePagination<RouterOutputs["user"]["list"]>(api.user.list);

  const firstUserEmail = paginated.items?.[0].email;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of TypeScript's generic type inference and conditional types.
import `ProcedureType` from @trpc server as well

Here `ProcedureType` type represents the type of your TRPC procedure (query, mutation, etc.).
The UseDatatableArgs type will take a generic parameter `TData` representing the type of the procedure, and it expects a query property that has a `useQuery` function accepting `BaseInput` as input and returning a ProcedureUseQuery type with the response type `{ count: number } & TData`.
Here's an edited copy of your code

```
import { ProcedureType } from "@trpc/server";
import { ProcedureUseQuery } from "trpc/react";

interface BaseInput {
  skip: number;
  take: number;
}

type UseDatatableArgs<TData extends ProcedureType> = {
  query?: {
    useQuery: (input: BaseInput) => ProcedureUseQuery<
      { count: number } & TData,
      string
    >;
  };
};

type PaginationResponse<TData extends ProcedureType> = {
  items: TData extends { data: { items: infer Items } } ? Items : never;
  count: number;
};

function usePagination<TData extends ProcedureType>(
  query: UseDatatableArgs<TData>["query"]
) {
  const [skip, take] = useSomethingThatManagesThis();

  const response = query?.useQuery({
    skip,
    take,
  });

  return useMemo(() => ({
    items: response?.data?.items,
    count: response?.data?.count
  }), [response]);
}
```